# validating start and end dates with jquery plugin: validation

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

i'm using bassistance jquery plugin validation and i have 2 textboxes for a start and end date. is there a way to setup a rule to say if either one is specified then require both fields, but the user can choose to leave both blank and that's ok?

thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify an expression to indicate whether a form field is required ([documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/required#dependency-expression)).

Lets say your form fields are called tbStartDate and tbEndDate, then your validation rules would be (untested):

```
$('#myForm').validate({
    rules:{
        tbStartDate: {required:'tbEndDate:filled'},
        tbEndDate: {required:'tbStartDate:filled'}
    }
});
```